# Отслеживание всех входящих соединений - bash

Tags: bash

Возможно ли написать на BASH отслеживание всех входящих запросов/соединений на IP виртуальной машины. И получить IP входящего соединения + порт

Comment: Баш не нужен, можно через iptables в сислог писать. А чтобы сислог сохранял в отдельный файл, его также нужно поднастроить. В общем, решение нагуглилось по "linux log all tcp" за 1 минуту, вот оно https://blog.dgunia.de/2015/09/04/logging-incoming-connections-tcp-linux/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если НЕ нужен мониторинг, а только текущие соединения GNU/Linux:

```
ss --all
```

Пример того, что можно получить (сами данные не показываю)

```
 ss -a | head -n1 | column -t
Netid  State  Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local  Address:Port  Peer  Address:Port  Process
```

```
-a, --all
    Display both listening and non-listening (for TCP this means established connections) sockets.
```

**ссылки**

- https://manpages.debian.org/testing/iproute2/ss.8.en.html